# How to cite an image from a website like this and which part should it be under?

Tags: citations

could anyone please tell me how to cite a picture properly from places like this? https://d2l.ai/_images/lstm-0.svg
The current latex code is.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \includegraphics[]{imgs/lstm-0.svg}
    \caption{LSTM}
\end{figure}
```

should I cite it under reference? or in the image caption? or in the footnote? or in the main text of my thesis when I mention this figure?

Is using the link of the image enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can access likeso:

```
@MISC{myimage,
    author = {{famous-scientist-on-departament}},
    title = {science-stuff},
    year = {2022},
    note = {[Online; accessed on access-date]},
    url = {https://d2l.ai/_images/lstm-0.svg}
}
```

Comment: thank you! so it should be mentioned under the reference part instead of the main body of the thesis?

Comment: and instead of in the footnote

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would cite it in the caption of the image (\cite{myimage} in Bruno Peixoto's good answer) and avoid footnotes as much as possible. You can also do so in the main text. I would not think that just putting the image in the reference section is a sufficient attribution. I am publishing in CS and know that other fields follow different conventions. Follow those first.

Comment: If you use \cite{myimage} in the caption in the image, the link of the image will appear in the reference part in the thesis? Do you think this is proper for the reference chapter?

Comment: It will appear in the bibliography, and that is good. I am unclear on what you mean with the reference chapter. Sometimes, there is a Related Work Section in a thesis.

Comment: Thank you! oh by reference chapter I mean the bibliography, cause it is under the reference chapter in my thesis. I felt doubtful because I didnt see others citing a picture in the bibliography before.

Comment: You should cite the image source in the caption or in the text when the image is described. I would greatly prefer it in the caption because people look at images sometimes without reading the text.